# Infinite recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion

While solving a problem in "Scala for Impatient" I encountered a scenario where I got my function into an infinite recursive call, but I don't know why.

The problem is:

```
Write a function that computes x^n, where n is an integer. Use
the following recursive definition:

x^n = y^2 if n is even and positive, where y = x^(n / 2)
x^n = x·x^(n – 1) if n is odd and positive
x^0 = 1
x^n = 1 / x^–n if n is negative

Don’t use a return statement.
```

While my answer is:

```
def positive(n: Int) = n > 0
def even(n: Int) = n % 2 == 0 
def odd(n: Int) = !even(n)

def power(x: Double, n: Int) : Double = {
    if (positive(n) && even(n)){
        val y = power(x, n/2)
        power(y, 2)     // problematic part, if substituted by `y * y` it works, WHY??
    }else if (positive(n) && odd(n)){
        x * power(x, n-1)
    }else if (n == 0){
        1
    }else{
        1 / power(x, -n) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to upvote this, but then I realised that two answers that came in on the same day as asking are not replied to. It is not mandatory to comment, vote or reply, but are you able to any of those things now, Muhammed? Did Daniel offer a good answer worthy of acceptance?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a simple case:

```
power(1, 2)
```

2 is positive and even, so it will call

```
power(1, 1)
power(power(1, 1), 2)
```

The first is positive and odd, so we get

```
1 * power(1, 0)
power(1 * power(1, 0), 2)
```

Now n is zero, so we get

```
1
power(1 * 1, 2)
```

Which simplifies to

```
power(1, 2)
```

Which is what we started with, so we'll loop everything again.

Answer (score 1):

when calling `power(y,2)` you happen to call back power with `n = 2`, positive and even again => infinite loop.